# How to pipe the result of a transformation chain to a function?

Tags: scala, higher-order-functions

I want to write a chain of transformations and finally have a block where I do something with the resulting collection, without using variables.
Is there a higher-order function on collections that just provides the collection on which it is called to the supplied function?

```
Query( ... )
  .map { ... }
  .filter { ... }
  .combinations(2)
  .pipeTo { col =>
     ...
     consolidate(col)
  }
```

Of course for a single function call one could do it like this:

```
consolidate(
  Query()
    .map { ... }
    .filter { ... }
    .combinations(2)
)
```

But the former reads more natural to me and allows e.g. for an easy injection of some conditionals.

A workaround I've been using is placing a match clause at the end:

```
Query()
  .map { ... }
  .filter { ... }
  .combinations(2)
  match { case lst =>
    ...
    consolidate(lst)
  }
```

But since this pattern occurs quite often I was wondering what is the idiomatic way to write this.

Comment: This might be a bit silly, but could you not just call consolidate on your whole chain? consolidate(Query().map(...).filter(...).combinations(2)) looks like it does the same thing your last example does

Comment: I covered that option in my second example, but it's not equivalent to the match example because the latter allows for additional processing besides calling a "consolidate" function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps the most idiomatic way would be to use the so called [Pimp My Library Pattern](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=179766), which allows one to add extension methods to any classes via implicit class conversions.

For example, to add a `consolidate` method to `List`s, you could write:

```
object ListExtensions {
  implicit class ConsolidatableList[T](val lst: List[T]) extends AnyVal {
    def consolidate = ??? // Do whatever you want with the List lst
  }
}

import ListExtensions._

List(1,2,3)
  .map(x => x * x)
  .consolidate
```

If you really want to be able to call arbitrary functions on arbitrary objects in a chain, you could even define an "pipeline" operator like in F#:

```
object Extensions {
  implicit class PipelineExtension[T](val obj: T) extends AnyVal {
    def |>[S](f: T => S): S = f(obj)
  }
}

import Extensions._

List(1,2,3)
  .map(x => x * x) 
  .|> (consolidate)

Query( ... )
  .map { ... }
  .filter { ... }
  .combinations(2)
  .|> { col =>
     ...
     consolidate(col)
  }
```

The `|>` operator behaves like the `pipeTo` method you have defined.

Basically, this works by creating an implicit conversion from your type to the type with the various extension methods that you define. The `AnyVal` makes the extension class an value class, so its use will have little to no runtime cost.

Comment: so I take it the Scala library doesn't offer such an operator in any form?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. Presumably, it's preferred to define extension methods as in the first example or to define intermediate `val`s to hold the partial results and then call functions on those intermediate `val`s.